# how to detect browser closing from web application working with master page?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have web application workung with master page.
I want to know when the user is closing the browser' then I'll raise event to clean' session variables.
How can I detect the browser closing/
I tried the unload jscript event' but it fired when I move from page to page.
Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (This is what we did in our project, Only 99% successful)

// Java Script Start

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
        try {
            e = e || window.event;

            // add any of your logic here.


        }
        catch (ex) {
            alert(ex.message);
        }
    }
```

//Script End

Just add this script anywhere on your page. its a windows event, which gets called "Before the window is closed". Please avoid doing time-intensive work here, that might lead to hang the i.e or worst crash it!

Regards,

Mazhar Karimi

Comment: in aspx page, don't add it in master page. just put anywhere in your aspx page.

Comment: It happens also when I redirect to next page' and not also when browser closed.

Answer (score 1):

Use an AJAX "heartbeat". That is, pool the server every 30 seconds or so using Javascript. If you don't recieve a response on your server in, let's say, one and a half minute, you can be pretty sure that browser window is closed. Unless your user disabled Javascript in the meantime...